# Blender is not rendering the camera view

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera

I'm new to blender so I don't know what happened to my scene but anytime I render this appears instead of my camera view:
[image]

What did I activate and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have more than one camera?

Comment: No, I have just one camara it looks like is rendering a noise texture of some sort

Comment: It looks like you have set a non camera type object as active scene camera. Select a camera in the 3D view and press `Ctrl`+`0` (Zero) or go to the *Properties Window > Scene > Camera* and pick your camera from the list

Comment: No, it keeps rendering that weird thing that i don't even have in my scene

Comment: @EstefaníaDeLaVegaGarcía to get your question answered please [edit] your question and add more information or make the file in question available. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It looks like a procedural noise texture from Cycles, so if Blender is rendering that it definitely is in your scene though it may be hidden.

Comment: Chances are you have an object close to the camera completely blocking the view... but again guessing is not what this site is about... please post more information...

Comment: Post the file to pasteall.org, then link it here. Then we won't have to guess.

Comment: I just encountered a new reason for Blender not rendering the Camera View... when I tried to do an actual final render in got an error: "No  area selected". Somehow I had specified the render border to be zero or something. Pressing Ctrl B while in Camera View, then marquee selecting the entire view fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have something hidden in preview mode, but not in your final render[image]

Check the little eye symbols to make sure they aren't transparent

You might also have some after effect in your compositing node setup that is broken.

Please post your blend file.

Answer (score 9):

Check also if you have a video in the Video Sequence Editor (VSE) that may block rendering the 3D view. You can swtich what to render (Compositor and/or Sequencer):

- go to *Properties Panel* > *Render*
- than Section “Post Processing”:
- if you have checked [x] Sequencer *and* have clips or media in the VSE, than the 3D view will not render but the VSE instead, i.e. the “Sequencer”. So in that case un-check it for the Sequencer

[image: Section Post Processing of the Blender-Properties panel Render]